# Hide Angular component if value is null

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a Angular application and I want to hide(not loading) a component if a value(array) is null.

THis I have as template:

```
 <div *ngIf="item.isJson !== null" >
            <div class="correspondence-item-p correspondence-item-message">
        <i class="fa fa-file-text-o  font-darkest"></i>
                <div *ngIf="!item.isJson; else summaryIsJson" class="correspondence-item-text correspondence-item-iframe-container">
          <iframe [src]="safeHTMLUrl"></iframe>
        </div>

                <ng-template #summaryIsJson>
          <app-dossier-entry-summary class="correspondence-item-text" [dossierEntry]="item"></app-dossier-entry-summary>
        </ng-template>
      </div>
   </div>
```

And this is the ts file:

```
export class DossierEntry {
  dossierEntryId: number;
  date: string;
  name: string;
  referenceId: string;
  summary: string;
  jsonSummary: Array<DossierEntryHeader>;
  isJson: boolean;
  hasFile: boolean;
  file: Blob;
  fileName: string;
  type: string;
}
```

And the ngOnit code:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.item.jsonSummary);
    if (!this.item.isJson) {
      if (window.btoa) {
        this.safeHTMLUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(
          'data:text/html;base64,' + btoa(this.item.summary)
        );
      } else {
        this.safeHTMLUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('data:text/html;utf-8,' + this.item.summary);
      }
    }
  }
```

So  in the console I get:

```
null
dossier-correspondence-item.component.ts:36 [{…}]
dossier-correspondence-item.component.ts:36 [{…}]
```

So the first item is null.

But I still see the component in the view when the value is null

So how to fix this? Thank you

if I do it like this:

```
 isJson: boolean = false;
```

and this:

```
 <div *ngIf="isJson" >
            <div class="correspondence-item-p correspondence-item-message">
        <i class="fa fa-file-text-o  font-darkest"></i>
                <div *ngIf="!item.isJson; else summaryIsJson" class="correspondence-item-text correspondence-item-iframe-container">
          <iframe [src]="safeHTMLUrl"></iframe>
        </div>

                <ng-template #summaryIsJson>
          <app-dossier-entry-summary class="correspondence-item-text" [dossierEntry]="item"></app-dossier-entry-summary>
        </ng-template>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Then the component is always not visible.

But it is the property:

JsonSUmmary:

see:

```
date: "2018-01-10T08:58:16.6610961+01:00"
dossierEntryId: 144
file: null
hasFile: true
isJson: true
jsonSummary: null
name: "6MWT"
referenceId: "62222050122220501"
summary: null
type: "attachments"
__proto__: Object
dossier-corresponden…tem.component.ts:37 
{dossierEntryId: 142, type: "attachments", date: "2018-01-10T08:56:02.7163505+01:00", name: "X-ECG", summary: null, …}

========================================================================
date: "2018-01-10T08:56:02.7163505+01:00"
dossierEntryId: 142
file: null
hasFile: true
isJson: true
jsonSummary: Array(1)
0: {name: "", order: 1, items: Array(26)}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
name: "X-ECG"
referenceId: "272222050122220501"
summary: null
type: "attachments"
__proto__: Object
```

When JsonSummary is null then not sowing.

I have it now like this:

```
<div *ngIf="item.isJson" >
            <div class="correspondence-item-p correspondence-item-message">
        <i class="fa fa-file-text-o  font-darkest"></i>
                <div *ngIf="!item.isJson; else summaryIsJson" class="correspondence-item-text correspondence-item-iframe-container">
          <iframe [src]="safeHTMLUrl"></iframe>
        </div>

                <ng-template #summaryIsJson>
          <app-dossier-entry-summary class="correspondence-item-text" [dossierEntry]="item"></app-dossier-entry-summary>
        </ng-template>
      </div>
   </div>
```

and this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.item);

    if (this.item.jsonSummary !== null)
    {this.isJson = true;}
    if (!this.item.isJson) {
      if (window.btoa) {
        this.safeHTMLUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(
          'data:text/html;base64,' + btoa(this.item.summary)
        );
      } else {
        this.safeHTMLUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('data:text/html;utf-8,' + this.item.summary);
      }
    }
  }
```

But the component is still visible

Comment: `item.isJson` is `boolean`. So try `*ngIf="item.isJson"` instead

Comment: simply try https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf

Answer (score 3):

In TS file make `isJson: boolean = false` and in html `<div *ngIf="isJson">` then after you get value for it change isJson to true

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI was typing the answer so didnt see. He wrote faster than me :)

Comment: best of luck for next time

Comment: @mightycodeNewton not `*ngIf="isJson"`. You should do it  `*ngIf="item.isJson"`

Comment: @HarunYilmaz there is no ```item``` object declared

Comment: @Massaget `item` is a property of the component (this.item). `isJson` is the property of `item`

Comment: ```if (jsonsummary !== null) {this.isJson = true}```

Comment: YOu mean in the NgOninit